# ListView is not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Simple Listview bind is not working.I am not understand what is the missing in my case?

Here I have downloaded project from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter19/ListViewList

Build successful and When debug code (android) then going perfect on the code but after debug got error like [image]

[image]

Without debug application crash.

Anyone have idea what is the missing in my case?

Comment: It is working on android 7 but it is not working on android 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug already reported in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41276).

I think that [PR 910](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/910) will fix this issue while running with pre-Marshmallow APIs.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, When android version is 5 on compile using android version then got error but it is bug with android version 5.